# Trapezium problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I am trying to solve the following geometry exercise:

In an isosceles trapezium the sum of its bases is equal to $6\sqrt{2}$ cm and the minor base is equal to the half of the major base. Suppose the height of the trapezium is $3$ cm. Calculate the exact value of its perimeter, area and diagonal.

First I've calculated the measure of each base:

Let $a$ be the minor base and $b$ the major base of the trapezium. We have $$a+b=6\sqrt{2}$$$$a=\dfrac{b}{2}$$

It follows $b=4\sqrt{2}$ and $a=2\sqrt{2}$.

I now that the formula for the area is $$A=\dfrac{a+b}{2}h,$$
where $h$ is the height, so $A=\dfrac{4\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}}{2}3=9\sqrt{2}$.

I don't know how can I calculate the perimeter and the diagonal, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Given the length of both bases and the height, how could you make use of pythagorean theorem to solve for the missing lengths?

Comment: I think a clever application of Pythagorean theorem should work. The diagonal will be the hypot. where some portion of your large base and the height form the other two legs of the triangle. Solve for the hypot. You will do this twice - once for each diagonal.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment because I could solve it after all, I didn't realize you had written an answer to my comment. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the minor base is on top, drop two vertical lines down from the ends of it to create a right triangle on each side of a central rectangle.  Can you use subtraction and pythagorean theorem to get the diagonal sides of the shape?